# Is there any idea to improve the scroll effect of listview like the rolling of cylinder?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am working on Android. Is there any idea to improve the scroll effect of listview like the rolling of cylinder?

I want to do this with the source of listview in Android.
Have you got a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Here I am given three xml tag they are improve the quality of ListView it is

```
 android:smoothScrollbar="true"
 android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
 android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Comment: Thank you all the same! I want to know can I modify the size of listview's item in bindView()? I use the CursorAdapter.